# IIS authentication UNC folder error

Tags: asp.net, iis, networking

I have a problem creating a website over a network folder

The network admin give me a domain user that can access the network resources:

[image: Acces to network folder]

Then i create a website pointing to that network folder:

[image: Create website to the network folder]

Change the option "Connect as..." and set a custom user (the one that network admin give to me)

[image: Entering network user]

Click on "Test Configuration" and give me this error:

[image]

Also tried changing Application Pool Identity and th error still there.

Funy things:

- The user HAS write and read access on the network folder
- When configuring the web site, IIS creates and modify a web.config file on network folder but then when running website it said cannot read the web.config

[image: Error at reading web.config]

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late answer. It's was a problem with the domain account. The iis was not in domain. So, in other server wich was on domain, try the connection and it was succesful.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue. Previously I've changed the permissions to give full access to the folder for the user and it's fixed this issue.

Comment: Thank you, in this case the user already has full access to the folder, may be is because one of the servers is on domain and the iis server is not?